# dig and nslookup commands are failing with a symbol lookup error

Tags: 20.04, dns

I can't pin down exactly when this happened as I don't run these commands overly often. General DNS resolution must be working seeing as I am asking this question.

I've seen similar issues on this site but the answers didn't seem applicable. As far as I know, just dig and nslookup are affected. wget and curl are both able to resolve URLs.

```
adam@latitude-7400:~$ nslookup
nslookup: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601: undefined symbol: deflate
adam@latitude-7400:~$ dig
dig: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601: undefined symbol: deflate
adam@latitude-7400:~$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7a472000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f0b01921000)
    libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f0b018f0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0b018cd000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0b018c7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0b016d5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0b01c82000)
adam@latitude-7400:~$ ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Oct 27 12:00 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601 -> libisc.so.1601.0.0

adam@latitude-7400:~$ sudo apt reinstall dnsutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libva-wayland2
  linux-headers-5.11.0-37-generic linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-37 linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-5.11.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dnsutils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,756 B of archives.
After this operation, 47.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 dnsutils all 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9 [2,756 B]
Fetched 2,756 B in 0s (12.5 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package dnsutils.
(Reading database ... 299655 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dnsutils_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking dnsutils (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.9) ...
adam@latitude-7400:~$ dig
dig: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601: undefined symbol: deflate
adam@latitude-7400:~$ nslookup
nslookup: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc.so.1601: undefined symbol: deflate
```

Comment: Is your system fully updated? After you fully update your system, you can try to reinstall these tools (using `apt --reinstall`).

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I tried reinstalling the dnsutils package but I got the same error.

Comment: Please, add the outputs of the commands you entered into your question text by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Done! Still the same as you can see

Comment: The commands `dig` and `nslookup` are in the package `bind9-dnsutils` (not in the package `dnsutils`). Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following: `sudo apt autoclean ; sudo apt autoremove ; sudo apt update ; sudo apt dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt --reinstall install bind9-dnsutils`, and `dig -v`.